# Usage of word routines, loop and repeat

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I saw some people used the word routine as repeating something in specific cases instead of loop or repeat, but for me it's a bit confused and not sure when should I use the word repeat or routine.

The main question is, Is the word routine changable as loop or repeat? If it's correct or not, what's the difference between routine and those 2 other words?

Comment: Please provide an example sentence to illustrate what you're asking.

Comment: Is this in a coding context?

Comment: Is the context performing arts of some kind, particularly dance? The word "routine" is often used for a choreographed series of dance moves which have been practiced thoroughly and are then performed as all or part of a show. A _dance routine_ is definitely repeated, often many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routine can be used as a noun, adjective, or verb (although it's quite rare and probably best avoided).

*Courtesy of Oxford Dictionaries*:

- NOUN: a sequence of actions regularly followed; a fixed program.
- ADJECTIVE: performed as part of a regular procedure rather than for a special reason.
- VERB: to organize according to a routine.

When "loop" is used as a noun it suggests one or more steps (a routine) that are *repeated*.  "Repeat", used as a noun, would refer to an event that is like some previous event, but not necessarily planned or fixed (like a routine would be).  "Loop", used as a verb, suggests returning to the starting point or step and "repeat", used as a verb, suggests doing something (like a routine) again.

So the words are related, but only "loop" and "repeat" are common as verbs and both imply repetition (where routine does not).  The only substitution I've heard would be "loop" (noun) and "routine" (noun).  (e.g. "John completed his daily loop." or "John completed his daily routine.")

Comment: Thank you all for comments and answer. Now I get it about those difference.